# p5js sketch slows down over time

Tags: p5.js

I'm new to p5js and I'm trying to plot incoming x y data by drawing circles which initially expand and then shrink becoming 'fixed' , but the speed at which the circles expand slows down over time - and I can't work out why. I have one array which stores the animated expanding / shrinking circle and another which stores the final state of the fixed circle.

```js
let circles = [];
let circlesStatic = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
  // e1 = new Ellipse(320,240);
  // e2 = new Ellipse(20,20);
  background(0);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  let e = new Ellipse(mouseX, mouseY);
  circles.push(e);
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].render();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < circlesStatic.length; i += 2) {
    // noFill();
    fill('rgba(50,50,50, 0.1)');
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke('rgba(100,100,100, 0.25)');
    circle(circlesStatic[i], circlesStatic[i + 1], 20);
  }
}

class Ellipse {
  // constructor
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x; // copy x argument value to the instance (this) x property 
    this.y = y; // copy x argument value to the instance (this) x property

    // current size - continuously updated
    this.size = 10;
    // minimum size
    this.minSize = 10;
    // maximum size
    this.maxSize = random(30, 35);
    // change speed for size (how much will the size increase/decrease each frame)
    this.sizeSpeed = 3;
    // internal frameCount replacement
    this.tick = 0;
    // this.fill=(255,0,0);
  }

  render() {
    // if the size is either too small, or too big, flip the size speed sign (if it was positive (growing) - make it negative (shrink) - and vice versa)
    if (this.size < this.minSize || this.size > this.maxSize) {
      this.sizeSpeed *= -1;
    }
    // increment the size with the size speed (be it positive or negative)
    this.size += this.sizeSpeed;
    console.log(this.sizeSpeed);

    if (this.size < this.minSize) {
      this.sizeSpeed = 0;
      circlesStatic.push(this.x);
      circlesStatic.push(this.y);

    }

    background(0);
    // noStroke();
    fill(200, 50, 0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    // this.tick++;
    // this.size = map(sin(this.tick * this.sizeSpeed),-1.0,1.0,this.minSize,this.maxSize);
    // fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    // ellipse(this.x,this.y, this.size,this.size);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that every time you render a circle it checks if it should become "static," and if it should it adds new values to `circlesStatic`. However, there is nothing to stop the animating circle to continue being rendered on subsequent frames. This results in massive numbers of entries being added to `circlesStatic` which means longer and longer render times. I've implemented one possible fix below. I also made it so that if you hold the shift key down you will see the previous behavior (watch the length of `circlesStatic` skyrocket after a few clicks). As soon as you release the shift key the fix will run and the number of entries in `circlesStatic` will plateau.

```js
let circles = [];
let circlesStatic = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640, 480);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
  // e1 = new Ellipse(320,240);
  // e2 = new Ellipse(20,20);
  textSize(16);
}

function mouseClicked() {
  let e = new Ellipse(mouseX, mouseY);
  circles.push(e);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  push();
  noStroke();
  fill('red')
  text(`circles: ${circles.length}; circlesStatic: ${circlesStatic.length}`, 20, 20);
  pop();

  for (let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
    circles[i].render();
    if (!keyIsDown(SHIFT)) {
      if (circles[i].isStatic()) {
        circles.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < circlesStatic.length; i += 2) {
    // noFill();
    fill('rgba(50,50,50, 1)');
    strokeWeight(1);
    stroke('rgba(100,100,100, 1)');
    circle(circlesStatic[i], circlesStatic[i + 1], 20);
  }
}

class Ellipse {
  // constructor
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x; // copy x argument value to the instance (this) x property 
    this.y = y; // copy x argument value to the instance (this) x property

    // current size - continuously updated
    this.size = 10;
    // minimum size
    this.minSize = 10;
    // maximum size
    this.maxSize = random(30, 35);
    // change speed for size (how much will the size increase/decrease each frame)
    this.sizeSpeed = 3;
    // internal frameCount replacement
    this.tick = 0;
    // this.fill=(255,0,0);
  }
  
  isStatic() {
    return this.sizeSpeed === 0;
  }

  render() {
    // if the size is either too small, or too big, flip the size speed sign (if it was positive (growing) - make it negative (shrink) - and vice versa)
    if (this.size < this.minSize || this.size > this.maxSize) {
      this.sizeSpeed *= -1;
    }
    // increment the size with the size speed (be it positive or negative)
    this.size += this.sizeSpeed;
    console.log(this.sizeSpeed);

    if (this.size < this.minSize) {
      this.sizeSpeed = 0;
      circlesStatic.push(this.x);
      circlesStatic.push(this.y);
    }

    // background(0);
    // noStroke();
    fill(200, 50, 0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    // this.tick++;
    // this.size = map(sin(this.tick * this.sizeSpeed),-1.0,1.0,this.minSize,this.maxSize);
    // fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    // ellipse(this.x,this.y, this.size,this.size);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```